# I’m a R beginner and having difficulty with the Divvy bike Trips capstone project: code chunks to remove NAs:

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I can't figure out where the problem is, but i don't have values on my "MIN' and i still have "NA" on my graph after using some codes like na.mit() and drop_na,pictures and code chunks are slated below:

```
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = mean)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = median)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = max)
aggregate(all_trips_v2$ride_length ~ all_trips_v2$member_casual, FUN = min)
```

[code to get min value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLMb5.jpg)

```
all_trips_v2 %>% 
  mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n(),average_duration = mean(ride_length)) %>% 
  arrange(member_casual,weekday)
```

I tried using these codes: `na.omit()` and p`rint(df %>% drop_na())` to remove the NA values but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: 0 is not “no value”, it actually means “zero” and thus might very well be the minimum of your data.

Comment: maybe you were showing someone else’s results. I think what seems a very possible (quite common beginner)“mistake” that you might not have reassigned a new object after removing the NAs with the above steps.

Comment: I got the same results before trying out those codes for the NAs.

Comment: For mean in summarize, after the variable name add `, na.rm = TRUE` .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: the code work (, na.rm = TRUE), Thanks guys!!!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. Please edit your question to turn the image into well-formatted text.

Answer (score 0):

For mean in summarize, after the variable name add , na.rm = TRUE . –
Elin
Feb 1 at 5:50

```
   all_trips_v2 %>% 
      mutate(weekday = wday(started_at, label = TRUE)) %>% 
      group_by(member_casual, weekday) %>% 
      summarise(number_of_rides = n(),average_duration = mean(ride_length,na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
      arrange(member_casual,weekday)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, the code worked, I appreciate your quick responds to my challenges. Thank you!